# The type or namespace name 'HtmlEditorExtender' does not exist in the namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit'

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">   
     <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager><ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManagerID="ToolkitScriptManager1"runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtEditor" runat="server"/>
        <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TxtEditor">                
        </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
    <br/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit"/>

</form>
```

> This is the design page and I add "<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>" at the top of the page

```
protected global::AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditorExtender HtmlEditorExtender1;
```

> I am getting error on this line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <configSections>
   <sectionGroup name="system.web">
    <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit" />
</sectionGroup>
 <section name="ajaxControlToolkit" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxControlToolkitConfigSection, AjaxControlToolkit" /></configSections>
 <system.web>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"></add>
  </providers>
</sanitizer>

  <pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>
</pages></system.web>
<ajaxControlToolkit htmlSanitizer="AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer.DefaultHtmlSanitizer, AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer" />
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="AjaxControlToolkit" publicKeyToken="28f01b0e84b6d53e" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.20229.24049" newVersion="1.0.20229.24049" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

> This is my web.config page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You register "AjaxControlToolkit" namespace with "asp" tag prefix, but access HtmlEditorExtender with "ajaxToolkit" prefix.
Change it to "ajaxToolkit" everywhere.